# Algorithms for combining dirty rectangles

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm moderately new to game programming, and I wanted to bring out the age old GamePanel again in C#.

I was wondering if there were any known performant algorithms that take two or more rectangles that represent dirty areas and combine them into one, for purposes of repainting only selected areas?

Comment: Extra cost of separately repainting intersected rectangles is that intersection is repainted twice. Extra cost of repainting combined rectangle is that some extra areas are needlessly repainted. Every merging of rectangles should consider the cost of merging, and cancel merging if cost is higher than benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like so:

```
// Computes the coordinates of the rectangle smallest
// rectangle emcompassing all given rectangles
int minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
minX = minY = MAX_INT;
maxX = maxY = -MAX_INT;
loop over all rectangles in var rect {
    if(rect.minX < minX)
        minX = rect.minX
    if(rect.minY < minY)
        minY = rect.minY
    if(rect.maxX > maxX)
        maxX = rect.maxX
    if(rect.maxY > maxY)
        maxY = rect.maxY
}
```

You might want to check for rectangle intersection first however. This way you can avoid combining rectangles that don't overlap at all.